# CSS Transition animation not working in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, css-transitions

am practicing on web design, so am working on  [this template](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/css3-animated-navigation-menu/)
i cant get the transition animation to work in chrome but instead its working fine in FF
am using transition ease-in-out, anyone can help me?

Comment: Perhaps add a jsFiddle of your code/problem? Your question is to vague to properly address.

Comment: sorry, what am asking is how to get the transition ease-in-out in chrome while its working in FF and Opera, i added -webkit- but that doesnt make it work, what is the problem?

Comment: -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; Should work no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `-webkit-` prefix to the transition property.